# Change property with vue.set() does not work

Tags: vue.js, set

Simple counter with increment, decrement, reset buttons and a list of the historic values of the counter : https://codepen.io/Olivier_Tvx/pen/JjdyBMO

**I want resetCounter() to clear all the previous historics**. I am not sure what is the proper way to do it. I try to change the 'visible" property to 'false' and filter it in the view, without success.

I get an error :  "[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined"

What I am doing wrong? Do I need vue.set here?

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
                return {
                  historics: [{
                      value: '',
            visible: true,
                }],
        timer: 1000,
                counter: 0,
            }
        },
  methods: {
    increaseCounter() { // Increase
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.counter++;
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => { this.pushToHistorics() }, 1000)
    },
    decreaseCounter() { // Decrease
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.counter--;
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => { this.pushToHistorics() }, 1000),
        console.log(this.historics)
    }, 
    resetCounter() { // Reset
      this.counter = 0;
      for (historic in this.historics) {
         Vue.set(this.historic, 'visible', false);
       };
      // for (historic in this.historics) {
      // this.historic.push({visible: false});  
      // };
    },
    pushToHistorics() {
    this.historics.push({
      value: this.counter,
      visible: true,
    })
    }
  },
  computed: {
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container align-center">
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="increaseCounter()" class="button rounded shadow success">
      Increase
    </button>
    <button @click="decreaseCounter()" class="button rounded shadow warning">
      Decrease
    </button>
    <button @click="resetCounter" class="button rounded shadow alert">
      Reset
    </button>
    <p class="text-center">
      Counter: {{ counter }} <br>
    </p>
    <ul>
    <li v-for="historic in historics.slice(0, 10)" v-if="historic.visible == true"> {{ historic.value }} - {{ historic.visible }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `visible` property for each `historic` then use `Vue.set()` to replace it in the current array.

```js
resetCounter() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.historics.forEach((historic, idx) => {
        historic.visible = false;
        Vue.set(this.historics, idx, historic);
    });
}
```

Or if you want to clear the `historics` array altogether, you can just set it to an empty array:

```js
resetCounter() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.historics = [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Would you recommand another way to hide the "historics" with a false "visible" property? I am still looking for a way to clear/delete data, but can't find one.